# Retrieve Comments parent on polymorph relationship with only specific columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Based on Laravel example Comment has polymorph relationship with Post and Video Model.

I can retrieve Comment with Post and Video using `$comment->commentable`, but it return all columns of Post or Video.
Post has id, name, other columns...
Video has id, title, other columns...

How to limit certain columns ?
I want for Post only id and name columns
and for Video only id and title columns

```
->with(['commentable' => function ($query) {
          $query->select('id', 'name');
      }])
```

This code will error since Video doesnt have name columns.

Comment: try with('commentable:id,name')